# R throws me an error after trying to update Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I had a problem with Rmarkdown tried to update it with following line

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

When I tried to knit a pdf report R gave me this error

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib. loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called `digest`
```

I read other with simular and tried this line of code

```
install.packages("rmarkdown", contriburl = "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib", type = "source")
```

R now throws me this error

```
   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib. loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called `digest`
```

And is terminated due to fatal error..

Any other information I need to provide? Any help please will need to knit my reports..

Comment: try closing any open R session, restart one, and reinstall the `rmarkdown` package.  Your system is having difficulty updating `rmarkdown`'s dependencies while you have them loaded into your session.  A clean session will usually resolve this.

Comment: I closed R, started and installed rmarkdown again from the toolbar but throws me the same error when I try to knit a pdf. Same error if I try to knit a html report. Can uninstall everything with rmarkdown and install it again to have a fresh start? Edit: Package missing now is `Rcpp`.

Comment: what happens if you run `install.packages("digest")` in a clean session?

Comment: I installed Rcpp this time and now package "stringi" was missed so installed that as well and its now working. 

Strange that installing rmarkdown didnt solve it? Thanks for your help!